# Postgresql 10 can't start server ERROR: streaming fail

Tags: linux, postgresql

Basically I've shutdown the server, didn't make a dump before...
Then start it again and it won't startup anymore.
The problem seem to be a the replication, is there a way to remove this before starting? 
Are there way to retrieve the database data or everything is lost?
I've found pg_resetxlog for previous versions but in 10 seems to be gone.

> 2018-01-05 17:09:07.895 CET [23815] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
>
> 2018-01-05 17:09:07.935 CET [23818] LOG:  database system was shut
>   down at 2018-01-05 08:37:53 CET
>
> 2018-01-05 17:09:07.935 CET [23818] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint
>   record 2018-01-05 17:09:07.935 CET [23818] LOG:  invalid secondary
>   checkpoint record
>
> 2018-01-05 17:09:07.935 CET [23818] PANIC:  could not locate a valid
>   checkpoint record
>
> 2018-01-05 17:09:07.936 CET [23815] LOG:  startup process (PID 23818)
>   was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
>
> 2018-01-05 17:09:07.936 CET [23815] LOG:  aborting startup due to
>   startup process failure
>
> 2018-01-05 17:09:07.939 CET [23815] LOG:  database system is shut down

Comment: Try `lc_messages='C'` in your postgresql.conf to get error messages in english.

Comment: In 10, pg_resetxlog has been renamed pg_resetwal as part of generally renaming xlog to wal. The root cause is data corruption in the WAL files, which should not happen unless hardware fails or the HD controller lies about sync() or fsync is off.